# How to use contentType field in CollaborationGroup standard object?

Tags: soql, community, salesforce1-app

I have using this soql query:

```
select Id, Type, ParentId, Body, LinkUrl, ContentType,CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Id, CreatedBy.Name, RelatedRecordId FROM CollaborationGroupFeed
```

Here Content Type is giving error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContentType - **Available in API version 36.0 and earlier only.** The MIME type of the file uploaded to the feed. This field is read-only and is automatically determined during insert. Need to change the version of your apex class/trigger.

[image]

[See the Reference Link for CollaborationGroupFeed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroupfeed.htm)

Comment: I know this field is read only but I want only use this field.But on developer console when i use this it gives me error.